# Solving the equation $\dfrac{(1+x)^{36} -1}{x} =20142.9/420$ for $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

How would one solve for x in the following equation:

$\dfrac{(1+x)^{36} -1}{x} =20142.9/420$

I tried factorising the top but that didnt really help much.

$((1+x)^{18} - 1)((1+x)^{18}+1)$

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did the equation come from?

Comment: Hopeless to get exact expression. In this kind of interest/growth rate problem, one needs to use a numerical procedre, like Newton-Raphson. Because the problem comes up often, various other specialized numerical procedures exist.

Comment: Since no one seems to have mentioned this yet, I'll point out that there is one real solution, whose numerical value is $x\approx0.015761329$ (found by numerical methods, obviously). There are also 34 other complex solutions, but I assume the OP is not interested in those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard example of an equation
that does not have an explicit formula for its root.
It can only be solved numerically.

The important thing is to get a good first approximation to the root.

For example, if you want to solve
$\frac{(1+x)^n-1}{x} = a$,
and you think that there might be a root close to $0$,
you can approximate $(1+x)^n$
by $1+nx+n(n-1)x^2/2$
(the first terms of the binomial theorem)
to get
$n + n(n-1)x/2 = a$
or $x = 2(a-n)/(n(n-1))$.

Then apply Newton's iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Make a change in variables: $y = x + 1$. Then the equation becomes:
$$\dfrac{y^{36} - 1}{y-1} = 20142.9/420$$
The numerator $y^{36}-1$ is equal to $(y-1)(y^{35}+y^{34}+\cdots+1)$ (use the formula for the sum of a geometric series). Therefore dividing by $y-1$ gives:

$$y^{35}+y^{34}+\cdots+1 = 20142.9/420$$

This is a polynomial of degree 35 in $y$. It happens to be that for polynomials of degree $5$ or higher there is no general formula to solve for $y$ ([1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)). You can find an approximate solution using a tool like [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/). Try inputting "(y^(36) - 1)/(y-1) = 20142.9/420" and see what answers you get for $y$ (there may be more than one). Then use $x = y - 1$ to get approximate answers for $x$.

Comment: I think you miss some thin like y-1 ?!

Comment: With that change of variable, the denominator is $y-1$. It's a good idea though. You can actually get a $35$-th degree polynomial since $y^{36}-1 = (y-1)\sum_{k=0}^{35} y^k$.

Comment: @proximal Oops! I'll fix that.

Comment: Since the right side is about $48$, it seems we can't have $y^{35}$ be even as large as $2$, so a reasonable starting value for $y$ is $2^{\frac 1{35}}\approx 1.02$.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28y^36-1%29%2F%28y-1%29%3D20142.9%2F420) gives $1.01576$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we want a small positive value for $x$, we can approximate $(1+x)^{36}$ as $$1^{36}+{36 \choose 1} 1^{35}x^1 + {36\choose 2} 1^{34} x^2+O(x^3)$$

With this approximation, the equation becomes approximately $$\frac{36x+630x^2}{x}=47.959$$

This can be rearranged as $630x=47.959-36$, which has solution $x\approx 0.01898$.

Comment: But OP had $(1+x)^{36}$

Comment: Thanks @Ross, funny I had it + then changed it all to - for some reason.

Comment: what is O? and this form the binomial expansion coefficients? if so how come we can diregard the other coefficients